# Not able to retrieve results from Open TSDB via HTTP

Tags: http, time-series, opentsdb

I have set up open TSDB using docker image. I am able to push data to database via HTTP post request.

```
[{
        "metric": "sys.cpu.nice",
        "timestamp": 1567764102,
        "value": 18,
        "tags": {
            "host": "web01",
            "dc": "lga"
        }
    },
    {
        "metric": "sys.cpu.abc",
        "timestamp": 1567764602,
        "value": 9,
        "tags": {
            "host": "web02",
            "dc": "lga"
        }
    }
]
```

Same data is also visible on the portal but I want to retrieve this data form TSDB by API.

I used this but it's not returning actual data.

http://localhost:4242/api/search/lookup?m=sys.cpu.nice{host=*}

```
{
    "type": "LOOKUP",
    "metric": "sys.cpu.nice",
    "tags": [{
        "key": "host",
        "value": "*"
    }],
    "limit": 25,
    "time": 6.0,
    "results": [],
    "startIndex": 0,
    "totalResults": 0
}
```

Could you please help to get data back from the database. I need to send this data to some other system.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [/api/query](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/query/index.html) endpoint

In your case you could try one of the following `GET` requests:

`http://localhost:4242/api/query?m=sum:cmp.sys.db{host=server01,tenant01}&start=1h-ago`

`http://localhost:4242/api/query?m=zimsum:cmp.sys.db{host=server01,tenant01}&start=1h-ago`

Comment: I am using http://localhost:4242/api/query?m=cmp.sys.db{host=server01,tenant=tenant01}&start=1h-ago and getting exceptionInvalid parameter m=cmp.sys.db{host=server01,tenant=tenant01} (not enough :-separated parts).

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you try these queries to see if that works for you?

Comment: Will above provide individual data points? If I have inserted 10 data point of single metric I need all of them.